# AngularJS - Simple $scope console.log() returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, logging, console, undefined

I'm trying to make a simple `console.log()` from this $scope:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerController" id="customer-block">

  <h3>Customer Information</h3>

  <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Address 1:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.address1" class="form-content"
        id="customer-address1" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Address 2:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.address2" class="form-content"
        id="customer-address2" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>City</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.city" class="form-content"
        id="customer-city" />
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my javascript file:

```
lima3app.controller("CustomerController", function($scope){

  console.log($scope.customer);

});
```

But the log returns me **undefined**. What's wrong with that?

This is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MU2i46o03bs22Jwh6QIe

Comment: The `$scope.customer` isn't initilized anywhere, so it's should be undefined. It will start to have data after you type something in those inputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the others have said, you need to initialize the customer object.

Since there is no value of customer set from controller, it is appearing as undefined in the view. When you enter values in the input boxes, this will no longer be undefined, but since logging is done only once initially, typing values in input box has no effect

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lMqPHVCekpAPGA0LPdIz)

Here is the part which I have changed in script.js

```
lima3app.controller("CustomerController", function($scope){

$scope.customer = {
  address1 : 'address1',
  address2 : 'address2',
  city:'city'
}

console.log($scope.customer);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your JS code

```
console.log($scope.customer);
```

run when you init the CustomerController controller, at that time $scope.customer has no value and it return undefined.