# How can this statement possibly return undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently in Chrome I made this observation while debugging an angularjs application.

```
console.log(scope.myObj.someProperty)
> undefined
```

and yet when I type in

```
scope.myObj
```

I get the collapsible tree representation of `scope.myObj` with `someProperty` clearly available as a key on the object with a value like `"hello world"`. It was not a member of `__proto__` but clearly right there as a key of `scope.myObj`.

How can this possibly be?

In other words: How can it be possible for `scope.myObj.someProperty` to be undefined when passing in as an argument to `console.log` and yet available for parsing when Chrome creates that collapsible tree?

EDIT: The second statement was executed immediately after the first, and the 2 commands were repeated about 3 times just to verify the output. I'm having a hard time replicating this to provide more code here, which is why the lack of context. I would rather not post the full source code of all the directives and whatnot from the angular app. The only sanity check I did was to check in with a few colleagues to verify that I wasn't completely missing something, which I wasn't.

2nd EDIT: This question has been marked as a duplicate of [AngularJS - Simple $scope console.log() returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901339/angularjs-simple-scope-console-log-returns-undefined). I don't think this is a duplicate because my question is not "why was my scope value undefined". My question is "why was my scope value undefined when using `console.log` to print it, yet available on the scope when browsing Chrome's collapsible tree view of the scope object?`.

Comment: Are you setting someProperty asyncronously? Please post more code and show us more context.

Comment: You haven't posted enough context here.